# Probability given CDF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The hospital period in days , for patients following treatment for a certain type of kidney disease is a random variable $Y= X-4$ with PDF:

$$f_x(x)=\frac{32}{(x+4)^3}$$ 
for $x> 0$

$$f_x(x) = 0$$ 
for $x< 0$

a) What is the PDF of the random variable $Y$?
b) Using the PDF of $Y$, what is the probability that the hospital period for a patient exceed $8$ days?
C) Using the pdf of $Y$, find the probability that a patient who has already been hospitalized for 8days will need to stay in the hospital for at least two more days.

PS: the first two parts of the problem are straightforward, however every answer I have found for part (c) misses the mark ( they don’t consider the fact that the patient has spent $8$ days already). Would you do $\frac{P(x>10)}{P(x>8)}$ or $\frac{P(x>10)}{P(x<=8)}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We shall compute

$$P(Y \ge 10|Y\ge 8)=\frac{P(Y \ge 10)}{P(Y \ge 8)}$$

In terms of $X$, it is equal to

$$\frac{Pr(X \ge 14)}{Pr(X\ge 12)}$$